# 2d Animation not playing second scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity2.0

I created a new animation for meteor GameObject , the animation functions in first scene normally, but the second scene is not playing regularly:
[video explanation of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8w25JU-pLYQ)

I think the reason for this problem is timeScale , and I added this code from meteor object:

```
void Start()

{

Time.timeScale = 1f;

}
```

The problem is not fixed by this.

Answer (score 0):

Animations are triggered by setting the value of an Animator object.

I.E.

```
[SerializeField] Animator anim;

void SetFields()
{
    anim.SetBool("flagName", true);
    anim.SetFloat("flagName", 0);
    anim.SetInteger("flagName", 0);
}
```

In your first screen, you must have some script that is setting the field of your meteor animator which has not been added to your new scene